# what happened when the Devas asked who are you to Lord Shiva?

Tags: shiva, gita

The Shiva Gita has the following slokas:

> मंदरं प्रययुः सर्वे मम प्रियतरं गिरिम् ।
>   स्तुत्वा प्राञ्जलयो देवा मां तदा पुरतः स्थिताः ॥ ८॥
>   तान्दृष्ट्वाथ मया देवान् लीलाकुलितचेतसः ।
>   तेषामपहृतं ज्ञानं ब्रह्मादीनां दिवौकसाम् ॥ ९॥
>   अथ तेऽपहृतज्ञाना मामाहुः को भवानिति ।
>   अथाब्रुवमहं देवानहमेव पुरातनः ॥ १०॥

I basically don't get what the translator is trying to tell us from the above slokas, a Hindi gives the following translation:
[image]

Which says something about lord Shiva taking the knowledge of the Devas and asked him who he was.(As I understand it).

So, my basic help needed would be to translate the above slokas a bit more clearly with a tail query of why did lord Shiva take away the knowledge of the Devas?

Comment: Reading above it seems like this episode is narrating/ reflecting story of Atharvasira Upanishad, you may read it! When Lord Shiva tells that he took away knowledge it may not mean that he made them ignorant. Shiva sutras in the second sutra say 'Jnanam Bandha' or 'Knowledge is bondage', Thus it should be this knowledge which Lord Shiva took and thus curiosity arose in Devas to know the Lord/Brahman/Shiva!

Comment: @Tejaswee , shiva gita is part of the padma purana

Comment: Yeah I know it, Puranas in many places take story from Vedas and Upanishads and explain it in a lengthy way!

Comment: @Tejaswee , oh, can you explain more in detail about this knowledge described?